# can access to standard java libraries be blocked by prohibiting import statements and java.* strings?

Tags: java, code-analysis, static-code-analysis

suppose I want to allow people run simple console java programs on my server without ability to access the file system, the network or other IO except via my own highly restricted API. But, I don't want to get too deep into operating system level restrictions, so for the sake of the current discussion I want to consider code level sanitization methods.

So suppose I try to achieve this restriction as follows. I will prohibit all "import" statements except for those explicitly whitelisted (let's say "import SanitizedSystemIO.*" is allowed while "import java.io.*" is not) and I will prohibit the string "java.*" anywhere in the code. So this way the user would be able to write code referencing File class from SanitizedSystemIO, but he will not be able to reference java.io.File. This way the user is forced to use my sanitized wrapper apis, while my own framework code (which will compile and run together with user's code, such as in order to provide the IO functionality) can access all regular java apis.

Will this approach work? Or is there a way to hack it to get access to the standard java api?

ETA: ok, first of all, it should of course be java.* strings not system.*. I think in C#, basically...

Second, ok, so people say, "use security manager" or "use class loader" approaches. But what, if anything, is wrong with the code analysis approach? One benefit of it to my mind is the sheer KISS simplicity - instead of figuring out all the things to check and sanitize in SecurityManager we just allow a small whitelist of functionality and block everything else. Implementation-wise this is a trivial exercise for people with minimal knowledge of java.

And to reiterate my original question, so can this be hacked? Is there some java language construct that would allow access to the underlying api despite such code restrictions?

Comment: http://www.javaworld.com/javaworld/jw-05-1997/jw-05-security.html this article mentions some of the tings you're aiming for :)

Answer (score 4):

In your shoes I'd rather run the loaded apps inside a custom `ClassLoader`.

Maybe I'm mistaken, but if he wants to allow limited access to IO through his own functions, wouldn't `SecurityManager` prevent those as well? With a custom `ClassLoader`, he could provide his `SanitizedSystemIO` while refusing to load the things he doesn't want people to load.

However, checking for strings inside code is definitely *not* the way to go.

Comment: +1, With a custom `SecurityManager`, he could inspect the stack trace and allow access to IO if the request came from his own library, but this is an equally valid option.

Comment: @Jeffrey: Ah, I see. I didn't think of examining the stack trace. But isn't that an expensive operation? Custom `ClassLoader` should incur no runtime costs.

Comment: It is fairly expensive, but `check` methods aren't invoked all that often.

Comment: your answer is interesting (I was ignorant of the Class Loader thingie previously) but I really do want an answer about source code scrubbing approach. Whether it can be hacked or not, and if yes how.

Comment: Source scrubbing is *much* easier to screw up than a proper security strategy. You might accidentally leave holes (such as using reflection to load classes by name, using `"ja" + "va."` to avoid detection).

Comment: @Amadan, to use Java reflection you have to import java reflection libraries, possibly java.lang.reflect. If you can't import them (because I scrubbed all import statements) then how would you use reflection to subvert my security model?

Comment: Seriously? `class Test { public static void main(String args[]) { try { Test.getClassLoader().loadClass("java.util.ArrayList").newInstance(); } catch (Exception x) { /* example so who cares */ } } }` Not a single import was given. Where did I need `java.util.reflection`?

Answer (score 2):

You need to check the `SecurityManager`. It is called by lots of JVM classes to check, before they perform their work, if they have the permission needed.

Answer (score 2):

You can implement your own [`SecurityManager`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/SecurityManager.html). [Tutorial](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/environment/security.html).